# class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{17})$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have  to show that the class number of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{17})  $ is $1$  .

First I know that $\sqrt{17}/2<3$ . Thus I only need to consider primes with norm $2$ . My problem is to show that these primes $a=(2,\sqrt{17}-1) ,b=(2,\sqrt{17}+1)$ are principal.

Thanks for the help .

Comment: Please see my answer to the original question, let me know if that helps or not.